# DualListBox getting values from second box

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

I'm learning Javascript and I have two listBoxes. I select food additives from first box and save it in the second box. Now I want to select all food additives from second box[image]

Here's my first listBox code

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
                <b>Choose food additives</b>
                <select name="from" id="multi_d" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
                    <?php include "connection.php";
                        $query = "SELECT food_additives FROM foodadditivestable";
                        $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
                        $i=1;
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                            $value = $row['food_additives'];
                            echo "<option value=DeicidS>" . $value . "</option>";
                            $i++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

and here's second listBox (I need to get info from this box)

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
                <b>Choosen food additives</b>
                <select name="to" id="multi_d_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="labas">Mano</option>;
                </select>
            </div>
```

Here what I try to do:

```
var selectedOpts = $('#multi_d_to').text();
    alert(selectedOpts);
```

but the problem is that I only get one result `"Mano"`. I moved food additives from first box using jQuery. So why I get only one result?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
$('#multi_d_to option').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).html();
  console.log(txt);
});
```